# sorting <li> elements alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, sorting

How can I sort an unordered list alphabetically while retaining outer html? My current setup sorts the list alphabetically, however it only rearranges the inner html of the list elements rather than the entire element, which is a problem because within the tag i have event based script calls that are specific to each element. The list elements themselves are added by script from an xml document.
Here's the html:

```js
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    onLoad(this);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "stocks.xml", true);
xhttp.send();


function onLoad(xml) {
  var x, i, txt, xmlDoc;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "<ul id = stocksymbols>";
  var StockList;
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Stock");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    symbol = x[i].getAttribute('symbol');
    txt += "<li onmouseover=\"mouseOver('" + symbol + "')\" onmouseout=\"mouseOut()\">" + symbol + "</li>";
  }
  document.getElementById("stockList").innerHTML = txt + "</ul>";
  sortList("stocksymbols");
}

function sortList(ul) {
  if (typeof ul == "string")
    ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var vals = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);
  vals.sort();
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}

function mouseOver(target) {
  stockInfoDiv = document.getElementById("stockInfo");
  stockInfoDiv.innerHTML = target;
}

function mouseOut() {
  stockInfoDiv.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
h2 {
  color: Navy;
}

li {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: Navy;
}

li:hover {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>List of Stocks:</h2>

  <div id="stockList">
  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="stockInfo">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you not just sorting it BEFORE you make the list? Sort the array, than build the list.

Comment: Because I was trying to do that for about an hour and couldn't get it to work. Then found this sorting function and figured I'd try it that way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of `lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];`, sort the `lis` list and do `ul.appendChild(lis[i])`. This will remove the current `li` from its position in the DOM and append it to the end of the `ul`. I'm assuming the only `li` elements are direct children of the `ul`.

```js
function sortList(ul) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("LI"))
    .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
}

sortList("stocksymbols");
```

```html
<ul id=stocksymbols>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>ZZZ</li>
  <li>MMM</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works great and it so simple, but it didn't work with Day 1, Day 2, Day 10, Day 11 where Day 1 appeared first (great!) but Day 2 appeared farther down the list, after Day 12.

Comment: I was able to get some help from Google Gemini

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="list-item3">text 3</li>
    <li id="list-item4">text 4</li>
    <li id="list-item2">text 2</li>
    <li id="list-item1">text 1</li>
</ul>
<script>
var list = document.getElementById('mylist');

var items = list.childNodes;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // get rid of the whitespace text nodes
        itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
}

itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML
          ? 0
          : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});

for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
  list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets do it with the XML, build an array, sort the array, and than build the lis.

```
var symbols = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Stock");
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
 items.push(symbols[i].getAttribute('symbol'));  //build array of the symbols
}
var lis = items.sort()  //sort the array
               .map( function(txt) {  //loop over array
                 return "<li>" + txt + "</li>";  //build the li
               }).join("");  //join the indexes as one string
console.log(lis);  //the lis in a string.
```