# Sort list item in custom order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a list like this

```
   <ul id="list">
        <li data-ind="1">L</li>
        <li data-ind="2">M</li>
        <li data-ind="3">S</li>
        <li data-ind="4">XL</li>
        <li data-ind="5">XS</li>
    </ul>
```

I want to sort them like this : XS, S, M, L, XL
how can I do this by injecting javascript/jQuery

Comment: See [Sort an array of objects based on another array of ids](/q/35538509/4642212) and [Sorting a list by data-attribute](/q/32199368/4642212). Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), how to [create objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype). Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: [sorting <li> elements alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722754) . Use [Sort an array in the same order of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377495) for sorting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` on the `li` elements and append them again in that order to the `ul` element.

The sorted position is dependent on the last letter (in reverse alphabetical order) and the number of Xs (I added some double X items to demonstrate):

```js
const seq = txt => "ML".indexOf(txt.slice(-1)) * txt.length;
$("#list").append($("#list li").get().sort((a, b) =>
    seq(a.textContent) - seq(b.textContent)
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li id="1">L</li>
    <li id="2">M</li>
    <li id="3">S</li>
    <li id="4">XL</li>
    <li id="5">XS</li>
    <li id="6">XXL</li>
    <li id="7">XXS</li>
</ul>
```